# Weird behaviour of char[]

Tags: c++, char

```
char a[5] = "hill";
```

I am confused... what *a* actually is? It is said to be of type *char**. It is a pointer, its value must be an address of the first character. And *a* itself must have an address. Surely these two addresses have to be different as *a* is of type *char** and the address it hold points to *char*.

```
std::cout << (int)&a << ' ' << (int)a << std::endl;
```

Oh well, the exact same address is printed out. Please explain me, what is happening here

Comment: `a` is an array, not a pointer. It can be used as a pointer to the first element because of a thing called *array decay*. This was answered countless times already...

Comment: Here's the link: [What is array decaying?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying)

Comment: a holds a number (seems like it when printed out with std::cout). How is a number an array? Looks like an address to me and nothing more

Comment: Read the link please. `(int)a` makes `a` decay from `int [5]` to `int *` (pointer to the first element), which is then converted to int.

Comment: @user3600124 It's clear from your comments you did not read the provided link. `a` will often decay to a pointer when it's used where a pointer is expected. In *those cases* it will behave as a pointer. In every other case, it's an array. Your `cout` statement is one of those cases that will treat it as a pointer.

Comment: Because `char variable_name[size];` is the official syntax of a char array declaration in C++?

Answer (score 0):

> I am confused... what a actually is? It is said to be of type char*

If you define an array like you do: `char a[5] = "hill;"`.
Then the following holds:

```
1. a     implicitly decayed to char *: decayed to a pointer to the first element
2. &a[0] is of type char *:            pointer to the first element
3. &a    is of type char (*)[5]:       pointer to an array which starts at the first element
```

All of them points to the same memory address but they are of a different type. Note that in case 1 the array name will be [decayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying).

> Oh well, the exact same address is printed out. Please explain me, what is happening here

That  means if you print out the address of either `a` or `&a` it will be the same. Also remember that if you want to print an address you cast the pointer to a `void*` and not just to an `int`.

> It is a pointer, its value must be an address of the first character. And a itself must have an address. Surely these two addresses have to be different as a is of type char* and the address it hold points to char.

With your assumption that the `a` points implicitly to the first element you're right. Also this variable has an address where the value that point to something is stored.

---

**Edit #1:**

**Proof of the above:**

Becaue several comments challenged, what I explained about `a`, `&a[0]` and `&a` here is the proof. Therefore I wrote this little not compiling C code:

```
int main()
{
    char a[5];
    double b;

    /* the following fails */
    b = a;     /* decay to char * */
    b = &a[0]; /* char *          */
    b = &a;    /* char (*)[5]     */
}
```

The compiler will fail and output errors and the expected type.

```
../src/SO_Test_C.c:6:7: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘double’ from type ‘char *’
     b = a;
       ^
../src/SO_Test_C.c:7:7: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘double’ from type ‘char *’
     b = &a[0];
       ^
../src/SO_Test_C.c:8:7: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘double’ from type ‘char (*)[5]’
     b = &a;
       ^
```

**sizeof():**

Here is what the different `sizeof()` operations are returning:

```
sizeof(a)     --> Array size:   5
sizeof(&a[0]) --> Pointer size: 8 (64bit) / 4 (32bit)
sizeof(&a))   --> Pointer size: 8 (64bit) / 4 (32bit)
```

Comment: 1 is incorrect.

Comment: @Slava: Thank you, I corrected it!

Comment: sizeof(&a) gives 4. If &a is of type char (*)[5] it shouldn't give 4 isn't it?

Comment: @user3600124: I extend my answer... Don't forget it is a pointer to an array note the `(*)`, so the size will be the pointer size which is on your system 4.